# flutter silder reach to end after 1 swipe in viewPager

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

I am using Slider on my project, I have a PageView, Its contains 3 pages and when I change the page I want to slider 1 step moves forward so I catch viewPager page from its controller:

```
pageViewController.addListener(() {
  controller.setPagIndex((pageViewController.page! + 1));
});
```

after swiping I rebuild Slider:

```
child: Slider(
  min: 1,
  max: state.length.toDouble(), // = 3
  value: controller.currentPageValue.value,
  divisions: 1,
  label: "${controller.currentPageValue.value.toInt()}",
  activeColor: mainRed,
  thumbColor: mainYellow,
  inactiveColor: backgroundGray,
  onChanged: (newValue) {},
),
```

But after 1 swipe and slider value being 2 the slider reaches to end?

> If I remove `divisions` it's ok and the codes work. the problem is
> because `divisions`.

[image]

Comment: Can you include full demo widget that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: It's full. a view pager with 3 items and finish

Comment: What is `controller` in this case , I guess `pageViewController` is being used

Comment: It's a getx Controller.  `  final currentPageValue = 1.0.obs;`

Comment: Can you provide Full widget without getx that will reproduce the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

divisions in a slider is the total number of equally divided sections in the slider. In your case you have 3 steps so the minimum division should be 2. Which will create 3 points and 2 sections in the slider.

```dart
child: Slider(
  min: 1,
  max: state.length.toDouble(), // = 3
  value: controller.currentPageValue.value,
  divisions: 2,//<-here
  label: "${controller.currentPageValue.value.toInt()}",
  activeColor: mainRed,
  thumbColor: mainYellow,
  inactiveColor: backgroundGray,
  onChanged: (newValue) {},
),
```

Comment: If the pages are dynamics? what happens to decisions?

Comment: Give length - 1 to divisions in that case. If there are only 2 values then only 1 division. One start point and 1 end point. If 3 pages then 2 divisions. Pont 1 on start, point2 in middle and point3 at end. And so on